# How to use global object within useCallback without having it as a dependency (remove warning)

Tags: reactjs, history, usecallback

I have this warning in my usage of Reacts useCallback hook.

***React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps***

```
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

    const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {

       const history = useHistory();

       ....

       const someFunction = useCallback(((param) => {
           history.push({
               search: `?myParam=${param}`
           });
           ....
       }), [history]); <-- Putting history object here removes the warning...

       return (
            <Fragment>
               <Something onClick={() => someFunction(myParam)}
            </Fragment>
       );
    }
```

Putting history object in the useCallback dependecy param removes the warning, but make no sense to have it as a dependency for this method. This method does not depend on the state of history, it simply calls it method to update the history. Furthermore, i suspect that my parent component will rerender each time history changes, which defeats the purpose of using useCallback.

My question is how to use history object within my useCallback method:

1. Without having the compiler warning (*React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*)
2. Without putting a ignore statement for the warning (*// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*)
3. Without using window.history since this does not work well with the use of useLocation() hook. History change events are not triggered by window.history. Therefore, cannot use useEffect & useLocation hooks as per example in this article: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/?fbclid=IwAR1WHJKKeF0rO_-jW31mRCatWq5o143OvgyURn6R3uGlHNQ_dqs3QQ4ddLs

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering how to fix the issue this is how I resolved it:

```
const navigateTo = React.useRef(history.push).current;
const handleLogUserOut = React.useCallback(() => {
    // Handle app logic...
    navigateTo('/login');
}, [ navigateTo ]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    handleLogUserOut();
}, [ handleLogUserOut ]);
```

I basically put `history.push` method inside of a `React.useRef` and calling that directly so that I don't have to have a dependency on the whole `history` object, causing an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any problems from including history in the list of dependencies? That worked fine for me and I didn't notice any extra rendering.

Don't forget that simply changing the state of history (e.g. navigating) is just mutating the existing history object, not creating a different one, so useCallback won't detect a change

Comment: I am using React `17.0.1` and I've noticed that if I include `history` in the dependencies array, it will cause my method to be re-created every time even though I'm only using `history.push`